# Have non clustered index but no clustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

If a table have two columns say (say Id and Name) has only non clustered index on name column but no clustered index, then what happens to performance of the table ?

Comment: All your performance of table are belong to us!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, which is for specific programming issues. Your question will (hopefully) be moved over to dba.stackexchange.com where it is more appropriate

Comment: [Take a look at this white paper](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc917672.aspx#EFAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you access it - a table with no clustered index is called a [heap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213609.aspx) an is not common.

If you *only* query by `Name` then performance will probably not be much different than if there were a clustered index on `ID`.  However any query that does a lookup by `ID` will perform a table scan.